# I am unable how this line of code is working

Tags: django, rest

```
class ReviewCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    # queryset=Review.objects.all()
    serializer_class=ReviewSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')
        # print(pk)
        watchlist=WatchList.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer.save(watchlist=watchlist)    
        print("1")
```

In the line serializer.save(watchlist=watchlist) why watchlist=watchlist is being passed.when i goes in CreateAPIView class of rest framework generic class there post method is implemented and from there on it is going into mixins class where create method is implemented like this.

```
class CreateModelMixin:
    """
    Create a model instance.
    """
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    def get_success_headers(self, data):
        try:
            return {'Location': str(data[api_settings.URL_FIELD_NAME])}
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            return {}
```

As control goes to perform_create function it is saving the data in DB but in our views.py we are again doing serializer.save(watchlist=watchlist).

Then why we are doing this again and how data is created in DB with only watchlist field value whereas Review model has other field also .Pls Help

Comment: so u are saying that this particular line "serializer.save(watchlist=watchlist)" is calling the BaseSerializer class save() method and their our rest of data(i.e rating,description,active_status field of Review class model) are already present only we are passing our watchlist to the rest of the data. correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The flow goes like:

1. CreateModelMixin.create **(rest_framework/mixins.py)**

   - init serializer with POST Data
   - Validate
   - Call ReviewCreate.perform_create **(you overrode the default preform_create)**
2. ReviewCreate.preform_create

   - `serializer.save(watchlist=watchlist)` / call BaseSerializer.save()
3. BaseSerializer.save() **(rest_framework/serializers.py)**

   - `validated_data = {**self.validated_data, **kwargs}` *(Add watchlist to rest of data)*
   - `self.create(validated_data)` / call ModelSerializer.save()
4. ModelSerializer.save() **(rest_framework/serializers.py)**

   - `ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)` Post to DB using vanilla Django

---

So the reason it can work when you only add the WatchList field is because of this line:

```py
class CreateModelMixin:
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # \/ <-- HERE!                      \/ <-- This!
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
```

Which pre-packs all your data.

And because you overrode the default `preform_create` method, you are only actually calling that `.save()` method once (in `ReviewCreate.preform_create`)